# How to unregister Mezzanine's Quick Blog from the Django admin dashboard?

Tags: django, django-admin, mezzanine

I'm subclassing mezzanine's BlogPost and have unregistered it to prevent it from showing in the admin page. e.g.

```
class BlogPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = ((None, {"fields": ("title",)}),)

    def in_menu(self):
        for(name, items) in settings.ADMIN_MENU_ORDER
            if "blog.BlogPost" in items:
                return True
        return False

admin.site.unregister(BlogPost)
admin.site.register(BlogPost, BlogPostAdmin)
```

However, this does not unregister the Quick Blog from the admin page.

[image: Quick Blog]

How do I prevent quick blog from showing up in the admin page?

The docs don't explain how to do this(http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/admin-customization.html#dashboard)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to remove `"blog_tags.quick_blog"` from DASHBOARD_TAGS setting ?

Comment: I don't even have DASHBOARD_TAGS in the settings. I've also tried setting DASHBOARD_TAGS to blank strings with not luck...

Comment: This answer did provide a good clue to follow though. To remove the quick blog from the dashboard you need to modify (or add) the `DASHBOARD_TAGS` setting, and remove from it the `quick_blog` tag, the default is this:
`DASHBOARD_TAGS = (
    ("blog_tags.quick_blog", "mezzanine_tags.app_list"),
    ("comment_tags.recent_comments",),
    ("mezzanine_tags.recent_actions",),
)`. http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/admin-customization.html#navigation

Answer (score 1):

inside your project create below folder structure

-templates -> admin -> includes

and inside includes folder create blank html called as quick_blog.html.
Thats it!

p.s "->" means folder inside folder mentioned before